# how to replace &#10; with empty string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to display outout of html instead of html tags so I used this regular expression.

```
String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '');
```

To replace the html tags and it removed all the html tags but I still have `& # 10;` in the text.

I guess it is for the new line character .

How do I escape it?

> & # 10;& # 10;& # 10;& # 10;& # 10;& # 10;& # 10;& # 10;& # 10; Where: Access code: 0164 125 followed by the # sign.& # 10; Review& # 10;-        New Template PRE DR template v03.xlsx& # 10;-       Information Regarding the change& # 10;-        Documentacion description Functionality, incidents and project code.
> -        Delivery software
>  - Test

Comment: well what effort have you made on that front?

Comment: & # 10; is being escaped in this text editor

Comment: post the actual input

Comment: This `<[^>]+>` does not represent, nor will get correct html tags. Isn't there an html cleaner you could use?

Comment: If you are trying to remove `& # 10;`, how do expect that regex that removes tags to do it? Try `String(text).replace(/& # 10;/gm, '');`

Comment: As a general rule, it's better to look for library functions to do this sort of thing rather than do it yourself. For instance, if you're using jQuery, doing `$('#my-element').text()` instead of `$('#my-element').html()` will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following code:

```
var text = "A string to have & # 10; removed"
text.replace(/& # 10;/g, ""); //Returns "A string to have  removed"
```

Note that the multi-line modifier (m) is not necessary.